Automate the data entry as per the service codes assigned and add Customer name along with their Location
I am working on a new master data of the services offered to different customers as per the service code assigned to them. However, there are 2 service codes assigned to a every customer. I want to automate this task instead of manually updating the customer's name to the adjacent service code and enter the customer's Location as well. I tried few formulas but they didn't work and messed up the data.
I want to get help from the experts here on how to automate this.
Spreadsheet 1 ( where in A1 - Service codes are assigned; A2 - Customer Name; A3 - Location of Customer ):

Spreadsheet 2 ( where the customer name and Location of Customer is stored ):

Desired Output:

PS: Is it possible to delete those "#" in B column in spreadsheet 1?
To match service codes refer below screenshot ( these are in spreadsheet 3 )

As always, I would like to thank the community.
Error:


How do you match service code with the given user name? How does those # appears?

Hi Evil Blue Monkey, I used one of the Vlookup and Index combination formula but it didn't work and left # in every cell. I manually entered the customer name as of now. To match the service code with user name. I will create a spreadsheet where the master data will be there. In Spreadsheet 2, Column A will have only service code ( only numbers i.e. before the "_" and in Column B, user names. I have attached one more screenshot for your reference in the above post. Can you please add this in the formula as well to match the service codes ?

Paste this in a new sheet:



Service code
User Name
Location

Service code
Name

Name
Location




9523645_FF
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B2,H:I,2,FALSE)

9523645
Ashley

Mike
India


9523645_CC
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B3,H:I,2,FALSE)

1259658
Mike

Ashley
USA


1259658_FF
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A4,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B4,H:I,2,FALSE)

1234567
Arjun

Arjun
Canada


1259658_EE
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A5,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B5,H:I,2,FALSE)

7654321
Raman

Raman
India


1234567_FF
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A6,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B6,H:I,2,FALSE)

2563147
Raman





1234567_GH
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A7,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B7,H:I,2,FALSE)








7654321_FF
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A8,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B8,H:I,2,FALSE)








7654321_MM
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A9,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B9,H:I,2,FALSE)








2563147_FF
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A10,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B10,H:I,2,FALSE)








2563147_LM
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A11,7)*1,E:F,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(B11,H:I,2,FALSE)









You can then edit the references in the formulas to match your actual ranges.

Thank you for the formula. I tried the above formula and it worked for the few cells but not working for all the cells and showing "#N/A" I have added the error screenshot above the post as I am unable to add the screenshot here.

A possible problem could be the storing of the data as text and not as numbers. To solve this, make sure numbers in column E are registered as such. If the error is noted by Excel, there should be a flag on the cells involved. Select them, click on the pop-up warning sign, select Convert to number. More information here.

Another way to solve such problem is to copy a cells that contains the number 1, select the affected range you want to covert, rightclick of the mouse on the selection, select Paste special, then select Multiply and Ok. Can't see why formulas wouldn't work, unless you've edited it. If you have indeed edited them, make sure that the range they referenced to are properly specified. For example in our case an address such as E:F can be swap with $E2:$F6 but not with E2:F6. This is because the dollar sign implies an absolute reference.

If address a range by an absolute reference, that range will stays the same no matter in what cell you are copying/moving your formula. If the reference is not absolute, it will be relative and it will change in case of copying/moving. More informations here and here. In fact if i change the reference in the formula i end up with the same error you are encountering leading me to believe you did change it.

Seems to be no need for the second table.
Your desired output can be derived solely from the first table by "filling down" those locations that are either blank or #.
If you prefer the "Merged Cells" output, you will need to use VBA as formulas cannot merge cells. In general, merged cells are not a good idea if you will need to refer to this table by formulas after the cells have been merged.
If you have 365, this can be done in a single formula entered into a single cell with the results spilling down:(Note that I used a Table, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer)
=LET(
    d, Svc_Codes,
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(d),
        COLUMNS(d),
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                OR(INDEX(d, r, c) = "#", INDEX(d, r, c) = ""),
                INDEX(d, r - 1, c),
                INDEX(d, r, c)
            )
        )
    )
)


Edit: If it might be the case that there are more than one blank or # sequential entries in the rows, then you can use this more complicated formula:
=LET(
    d, Svc_Codes,
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(Svc_Codes),
        COLUMNS(Svc_Codes),
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                OR(INDEX(d, r, c) = "", INDEX(d, r, c) = "#"),
                INDEX(
                    d,
                    XMATCH(
                        1,
                        (INDEX(d, SEQUENCE(r - 1), c) <> "") * (INDEX(d, SEQUENCE(r - 1), c) <> "#"),
                        0,
                        -1
                    ),
                    c
                ),
                INDEX(d, r, c)
            )
        )
    )
)


Hi Ron, from where does the first formula pull information from regarding the customer name and locations? Is the information in the same sheet here or in spreadsheet 1, 2 ?

@RamanSingh As it shows in the screenshot, it obtains it from what you termed Spreadsheet 1 in your question and converts it to your desired output. But see my second answer in case you did not intend that to be your original data.

@RamanSingh To further clarify, it pulls the name and country from the last non-blank (non-#) name and/or country in the original data, which is the same as you show in Spreadsheet1 in your question

I am adding another answer because, after reading some of your comments, I am uncertain as to what your original data looks like. I will delete whichever answer is inappropriate.
If your original data consists of three tables (Named as shown):

Then the following formula, entered into a single cell, will SPILL the desired results:The formula uses multiple lookups to determine the correct answer.
=LET(
    _d1, SvcCodes_Used,
    _d2, SvcCodes_Names,
    _d3, Names_Location,
    VSTACK(
        {"Service Code", "Name", "Location"},
        MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(_d1),
            3,
            LAMBDA(r, c,
                IF(
                    c = 1,
                    INDEX(_d1, r, c),
                    LET(
                        nm, XLOOKUP(--TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(_d1, r, 1), "_"), CHOOSECOLS(_d2, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_d2, 2)),
                        IF(c = 2, nm, XLOOKUP(nm, CHOOSECOLS(_d3, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_d3, 2)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)



Thank you Ron. I tried the above formula but it is showing broken formulas

@RamanSingh I don't know what you mean by "broken formulas". Please explain.

@RamanSingh In this response, as I implied, I made assumptions about what your original data looks like. But if it does not, and if you've never posted your original data, then we are dealing with a GIGO situation.

Spreadsheet 1 is the sheet where the desired output I want. The "#" is due to the other formula I used but It didn't work and I deleted it but "#" were left and does not have any formula in those cells. Spreadsheet 2 has the customer name and location. Spreadsheet 3 has the service code and customer name ( I added this after "Evil Blue Monkey" asked me from where am I pulling the data from. I am sorry if the above question was not drafted properly and got you confused.

@RamanSingh You need to post examples of your original data and also tell me what you mean by broken formulas. If your original data looks like your spreadsheet 1 then my previous answer is appropriate. If it looks different from that, I won't be able to help you unless you can present an example of what it actually looks like.
